# Linux: How to allow a regular user to "su - anotherUser"?

Tags: scripting, sudo, su

I wrote a Nagios check script which checks if user peeradmin is able to touch a file in some mount on the server.

Nagios user is: nagios .

I've edited `/etc/sudoers` and added these lines but none worked:

```
nagios  ALL=NOPASSWD: /bin/su - peeradmin -c /bin/touch
nagios  ALL=(peeradmin) NOPASSWD: /bin/su
nagios  ALL=(peeradmin) NOPASSWD: /bin/su - peeradmin
```

But still, while logged in as nagios user i'm unable to run any command as user peeradmin without being asked for a password:

```
[nagios@hadoop-nn1 ~]$ su - peeradmin -c "ls"
Password:
```

What am I doing wrong and how can I allow user nagios to run commands as user peeradmin?

Thanks in advance,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Though correct, I think the above answer is a little incomplete.

In order to do both `touch` and `ls` as peeradmin user, the rule in `/etc/sudoers` file should look like:

`nagios ALL=(peeradmin) NOPASSWD: /bin/ls, /bin/touch`

If you would like to run more commands, then add those commands (with full path) separated with a comma.

Once you do that, just use the following commands as nagios user:

`sudo -u peeradmin touch /path/to/the/mount`

or

`sudo -u peeradmin ls`

Answer (score 3):

That's because it's `sudo` config, and you don't run `sudo`.

`sudo su - peeradmin -c "ls"` might work.

But really, should should be thinking more in terms of using sudo directly if it's just running commands. e.g.

```
sudo -u peeradmin ls
```

For which you'd need an alias:

```
nagios ALL=(peeradmin) NOPASSWD: /bin/ls
```