# Icinga2 - Unknown user:backuppc

Tags: linux, backup, icinga, backuppc

I'm trying to monitor BackupPC with Icinga2.I've downloaded [this plugin](https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Backup-and-Recovery/BackupPC/check_backuppc-%28new%29/details) but I'm getting the following error.

[image]

I've added this to `commands.conf`

```
object CheckCommand "backuppc" {
        import "plugin-check-command"

        command = [ "sudo", "-u  backuppc",  PluginContribDir + "/check_backuppc" ]

        arguments = {
                "-w" = "$warn_lvl$"
                "-c" = "$crit_lvl$"
                "-v" = "$verbose$"
        }
}
```

This was added to `\etc\sudoers`

```
Defaults:nagios !requiretty
nagios  ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_backuppc
```

And this was added to `services.conf`

```
apply Service "backuppc" {
   import "generic-service"

   check_command = "backuppc"
   vars.warn_lvl = 14
   vars.crit_lvl = 30
   vars.verbose = ""

   assign where host.name == NodeName
}
```

Backuppc user exists and the command is working, when I run it from shell:

```
root@backup:/# sudo -u backuppc ./usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_backuppc
Use of qw(...) as parentheses is deprecated at /usr/share/backuppc/lib/BackupPC/Storage/Text.pm line 302.
Use of qw(...) as parentheses is deprecated at /usr/share/backuppc/lib/BackupPC/Lib.pm line 1425.
BACKUPPC CRITICAL ( 1 OK, 0 UNKNOWN, 0 WARNING, 1 CRITICAL)
```

Ty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is the way you put the command into Icinga2.

When you write:

```
command = [ "sudo", "-u  backuppc",  PluginContribDir + "/check_backuppc" ]
```

This gives the system a argument list, that puts

```
"-u  backuppc"
```

as a *single* argument. Now sudo tries to find the user "  backuppc", with 2 spaces.

You should either write: (2 arguments)

```
"-u", "backuppc"
```

Or: (Single argument without space)

```
"-ubackuppc"
```

Usually spaces are meant to separate arguments, but only when parsed by a shell (like bash).

Icinga2 tries to run command in a safe way, so that shell code injection should not happen.

Answer (score 1):

The other answer from @lazyfrosh points to the problem perfectly. But there are two things I would like to add.

- The way you are testing will always work, as you are logged in as `root`. If you want to test if user `nagios` is able to run the script, then first login as `nagios` and then run the command using `sudo` to see if it works.
- Considering security, you may assign `nagios` user the sudo privilage limited to what only necessary to run the script as user `backuppc` and nothing more. Something like:

  `nagios ALL=(backuppc) NOPASSWD: /usr/lib/nagios/plugins/check_backuppc`

May be you will need to adjust it according to the script.

See this for similar info: [Linux: How to allow a regular user to "su - anotherUser"?](https://serverfault.com/questions/653141/linux-how-to-allow-a-regular-user-to-su-anotheruser)

Comment: He put in "(ALL)" for the target user, so that can't be the problem... But yes, testing with the user Nagios is appreciated. Though the error suggests my described problem.